# how to preserve the recipes when we run chef client with a new recipe with -o option

Tags: knife, chef-infra

Though the run_list is preserved over the node when we run chef-client with -o option , but how to make sure that the recipes run are also preserved.

Comment: by "recipes run" do you mean the `node.recipes` attribute?

Answer (score 0):

chef-client -o is an override to a node's existing run_list, not an append to the node's existing run_list.  It would be better to add the recipe you want to the node's run_list via:

```
`knife node run-list add`
```

or chef-server UI and then re-run chef-client on the node with no override option.

https://docs.getchef.com/knife_node.html#run-list-add